# Infopath 2013 Repeating table

Tags: infopath

I have looked at Google search but not able to find answers.

Problem:I want to populate a number of fields from a dropdown when a user selects a dropdown value.

[image]

If I select Tesco, I want the name, email, address number to be populated.

The email field is a repeating table. When I select a dropdown value, the data does not populate email address. Does anyone know why? Any other solutions?

If I use, repeating sec it works fine but same email copied number of times. Not sure why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the following video to establish exactly what you have an it worked perfectly try it out : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mATsK0aVZ9I ( the actually logic and rules behind the binding of data start at about 3 minutes in )

- The tricky part is to make the rules between the feilds to be exactly the way it is in the video, if some of the data filtered is not correct based on the feilds it will not work, or only give you the first text from each list.

Comment: VKay, I am trying to follow the video link. When I click on repeating table property I do not have the rules button appearing! Any idea?

Comment: It should, sometimes it does not appear automaticlly try to select the feild then on the top ribbon go to Properties (Control Tools) and there click on ADD RULE or MANAGE Rule see if that works.

Comment: I am afraid no luck. I can see the Add rule button but it is not allowing me to add the rule. It is disable! Not sure what else to do.

Comment: I added another repeating table and I am able to add rules. I will work this. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear, no problem let me know if you need anything else !

Comment: Hi VKay, the repeating table rules button is still disabled. I have Office professional Plus 2013. Any idea why rules button is not appearing?

Comment: Hi, I have solve the issues by adding dropdown list as part of repeating table and able to add the rules. Thank you all for answering.